# Use node js to access a local network drive

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, electron

NodeJs is great when it comes to fs/io operations, but I couldn't use to access a shared (for storage) local network drive.

```
filesystem.writeFile('\\192.168.1.1\test.txt', 'data!', function(error){ ... });
```

I get UNKNOWN_ERROR which is not helping! The IP up there is accessible through the explorer (I am on windows) with no problem, and writable (for my windnows user).

What is the problem here ?!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remember that in a JavaScript string literal, `\` is an escape character. The actual filename you've asked that to write to is `\192.168.1.1<tab>est.txt` (where `<tab>` represents a tab character), because `\\` => `\` and `\t` => tab.

To put a backslash in a string using a string literal, you need to escape it (with a backslash):

```
filesystem.writeFile('\\\\192.168.1.1\\test.txt', 'data!', function(error){ ... });
```

Comment: Is that enough to trigger SMB access? Since [modules exist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/smb2) for the purpose, I wouldn't have expected it to.

Comment: @Quentin: That's enough to hand off to the OS's file APIs, which take it from there. So whether it's enough to access what they're trying to access will depend on their environment. That path looks dodgy to me, because it starts with a double backslash and a server name (IP in this case), but isn't then followed by a share name. I'd expect `\\server-or-ip\share\path` (e.g. `"\\\\server-or-ip\\share\\path"`). But I only know so much about SMB...

Comment: @Quentin: Just tried it on a Windows box. Yes, it's sufficient, if the path is correct.

Comment: Yeah sure, my bad, but I am still seeing the same error. The "unknown error" thing is very frustrating :(

Comment: @Dewan159: First thing to do is check the path. You seem to be using Windows (the backslashes in file paths are a giveaway). Normally I would expect an SMB path like that to be `\\server-or-ip\sharename\path`, not just `\\server-or-ip\path`. So my first step would be to open a command prompt and do `dir \\192.168.1.1\test.txt` and see if I got an error. If I didn't, I'd then do `echo "foo" > \\192.168.1.1\test.txt` to see if there's an issue with writing.

Comment: ammm, I am getting "access denied" ! but how ?! I can access it as usual through the explorer and do whatever I want.

Comment: @Dewan159: Again, I urge you to check the path, as the path is quite suspect. In any case, the NodeJS part is (now) correct.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well, the path IS right, ... thanks I will try to find a work around.

Comment: @Dewan159: Okay. Meanwhile, the question you had about NodeJS is answered: With the correction to the backslashes, that code is valid. The problem is elsewhere.