# Nodejs : Writing file to a unix network location

Tags: node.js, unix, networking, ftp, fs

I was trying my hands at writing/reading a file to a network location using node.js.

I used the file path as prescribed here :
[Use node js to access a local network drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837954/use-node-js-to-access-a-local-network-drive).

I tested my code on windows machine and network location was my workplace network where many systems were seen visible on the Network in My Computer.I was able to successfully read/write a file to any of these Network systems.

After this I tried the same code with a UNIX machine , for which I was provided a username/password and a machine IP.

However when I ran the same code with path changed I am getting an error saying:

```
  { [Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, open '\\<IP-Address>\home\rstudio\work\ru
    ing\helloWorld.txt']
      errno: -4094,
      code: 'UNKNOWN',
      syscall: 'open',
      path: '\\\\<IP-Address>\\home\\rstudio\\work\\running\\helloWorld.txt' }
```

Following is my code :

```
var fs = require("fs");

fs.writeFile('\\\\<IP-Address>\\home\\rstudio\\work\\running\\helloWorld.txt', 'Hello World!', function (err) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log('Hello World > helloWorld.txt');
});
```

For windows , I was putting the machine name instead of the IP-Address.

Please let me know the reason for the error and also what should I do to successfully write file in the second case.

Answer (score 0):

Local network drives in Windows (For example drive W:) is synonymous to mounted files systems in UNIX (for example /foo).

If the mount is proper, then the writeFile API will work without issues, except that the path specifier should be according to UNIX convention (forward slashes instead of double backslashes).

If the file resides is in another system and the file system is not mounted, then this mechanism does not work. You will need a client-server program pairs to send, receive and write the data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So you mean to say the file system I am trying to access from unix system isn't mounted ? If that is the case , if I mount the file system of unix on windows I shall be able to run the above code successfully?

Comment: I doubt whether you can mount a UNIX FS to windows for 2 reasons: i) the low level file format of both are different, and ii) UNIX fs access always require authentication, so a direct mount model does not seem to be feasible. However, I am not an expert in this area, so I cannot provide more details here.