# Accessing a network drive in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking

I'm trying to list the files in the S:/test folder, which is in my network (it's not a local directory). I was wondering how to do this? The code so far looks like this:

```js
const testFolder = 's:/test';
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    console.log(file);
  });
})
```

I've tried changing the path to S:test, s:\test to no avail, the error is always "Cannot read 'forEach' of undefined"

Comment: please use the full address of the drive (s is just a short version of a full path)... this post might assist you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837954/use-node-js-to-access-a-local-network-drive

Comment: You're right, I thought i had tried that but i was wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Also catch the error first, `if (err) return console.error(err)` or even better use a Promisified `fs`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this is windows (which I assume it is), then you need to do a couple things:

1. Use the full path (drive letters are OK, but you can also use UNC paths in windows) to the desired directory.
2. Escape any backslashes in a string definition with an extra backslash.
3. Always use error handling on your `fs.readdir()` callback so if there is an error, you can see exactly what the error is.

Working code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const testFolder = 's:\\test';

fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  files.forEach(file => {
    console.log(file);
  });
});
```

I just tried this code on my own hard drive and it works just fine.

---

And, FYI I pretty much always use ES6 `for/of` now in modern node.js rather than `.forEach()` because it's much more efficient for the interpreter and it gives you more loop control (for example, you can use `break` to exit the loop).

```
const testFolder = 's:\\test';
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  for (let file of files) {
    console.log(file);
  }
});
```

Comment: excelent, thank you for the thorough response! is it really more efficient to use for of?

Comment: for/of or Promise.all() if you're fetching

Comment: Brilliant! Very helpful

Comment: what about for mac?

Comment: I know this post is old but I have the similar problem. I can read the contents of the folder without problem if I run my application with "node application.js" but if I install my application as a service I get the error "enoent

Comment: @Juan - That sounds like you're probably relying on the current working directory for your file access and that has a different value when it's run as a service.  You probably need to construct filenames relative to your current module's directory and build a full path.  This is just a guess since we can't see any of your code.  If you need more help, please write your own question and show your relevant code in that question.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I posted an question about this problem. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74017600/node-windows-service-and-network-drive-access) And my code works perfectly when I run my application with "node application.js" the problem is linked with Service I think