# Node - Windows service and network drive access

Tags: node.js, networking, service, drive

I developed a Node JS application that allows you to browse a folder and then send a file from this folder in FTP.
If I run my application with the following command: `node application.js` :

- I can browse the contents of a folder locally
- I can browse the contents of a folder of a network drive

If I run my application through a service installed on Windows (`using "require('node-windows').Service"`) :

- I can browse the contents of a folder locally
- I **can't** browse the contents of a folder on a network drive

  I get an error

  ```
  W:\my_folder\ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'W:\my_folder\'
  ```

Does anyone have any idea why my application running as a service can't browse network drives...?

I did some tests with my Application launched in Service Mode.

"W:\my_folder" -> `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'W:\my_folder\'`

"\192.168.1.X\my_folder" -> `Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir '\\192.168.1.X\my_folder\'`

"\server_name\my_folder" -> `Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir '\\server_name\my_folder\'`

While all these **tests work** if I run my application with "**node application.js**"

I made a very simple code to explain how the application works. Code that works in console mode but not in service mode :

```
// Initialization
var logFolder   = "logs";
var testFolder  = "W:\\folder_test";


try
{
    // Get Folder Content
    folderContentList = fs.readdirSync(testFolder);

    // Write Log (this is a personnal fonction)
    writerLog(fs,path,logFolder,testFolder+' - '+folderContentList.length+'');
}
catch(err)
{
    // Write Log (this is a personnal fonction)
    writerLog(fs,path,logFolder,testFolder+' - ERR : '+err);
}
```

In my application (simple version) I traced the name of the user using the application. And by modifying my Service under Windows I managed to obtain the same user as the one used in console mode. But :

- With the same app
- With the same user

My script works in Console mode and not in Service mode. **I cannot browse the network drive in Service mode**. I'm disappointed :(

Comment: You need to start you service *after* the network is available, and all drives you wanted are mounted. Not to mention to set your user/service the correct rights. Dont know how to do this on Windows. Thinks like that are a lot easier in Linux.

Comment: @Marc Thank you for your comment. The disks are well mounted before the start of the service. I am looking on the side of the rights because indeed it can come from there. 
And yes it's probably easier on Linux :)