# Nodejs access shared folder on local network, root directory problem

Tags: node.js, directory, filesystems, subdirectory, local-network

When trying to access shared folder on local network, the following works:

```
fs.readdir('\\\\192.168.178.28\\temp2', (err, files) ...
```

while, the following gives error

```
fs.readdir('\\\\192.168.178.28\\', (err, files) ...

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\192.168.178.28'] {

  errno: -4058,

  code: 'ENOENT',

  syscall: 'scandir',

  path: 'C:\\192.168.178.28'

}
```

If subfolder is not specified, Node takes it as local C: drive despite \ as hostname IP.

I tried other functions and methods, as well as Path module. All give similar results.

related Info:
[Use node js to access a local network drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837954/use-node-js-to-access-a-local-network-drive)

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: There is no file access in Windows to a path that starts only with an IP address.  For file access on a remote computer, you have to access a Window share name (the name of some resource that was shared from that computer).

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I checked with Java and got the same error.

My problem: 

I need to access data saved in a microcontroller with a 1 to 1 wifi connection to my computer. I can ping the IP successfully, and I know data were saved there, but I don't know the directory name.

Is there any way to figure it out?

Comment: That depends entirely upon the microcontroller OS and what it makes available to the outside world.  For example, does it support Samba file sharing?  Or can you put a little tiny web server on it that will serve the file you want?  Or does it offer some other sort of programmatic access to its file system over the network?

Comment: Thanks for the indications. I'm not familiar with these but will check. 

It provides an ip + socket 8080. General Info as follows:

DHCP
SSID: My-Link
Protocol: 802.11g
Security type: Open
Network band: 2.4 GHz
Network channel: 1
Link speed (Receive/Transmit): 54/54 (Mbps)
Link-local IPv6 address: fe80::68d2:dba6:cbff:23a%9
IPv4 address: 192.168.4.2
IPv4 DNS servers: 192.168.4.1
Manufacturer: Intel Corporation
Description: Intel(R) Wireless-N 7265
Driver version: 19.51.30.1
Physical address (MAC): 94-65-9C-0D-05-B6

Comment: Please provide a link to the actual product and to the developer documentation for using it.  How to answer this is specific to the specific controller/configuration you have so there is no way to answer it without knowing the fine details of what product and configuration you're using.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. I'm trying to get those info. This is kind of a home-made device with a magnetic sensor and measure some property of metals. After several years it's difficult to contact the original developer. Anyway, many thanks!

Comment: Do you have any ability to put a web server on it?  Or it just outputs sensor values with no custom programming available?

Comment: I have a small android software which can (1) download data files from device to phone, or (2) online show measurement results on cell phone. I was told with wifi connection the program can be "easily" done (no need for low level communication or driver programming). I'm trying to extend that android program: (1) read measurement data from device online, (2) submit to database, (3) show remote colleague on webpage. No problem with 2 and 3 but I'm blocked on step 1.

Answer (score 0):

### Information I collected in the last days:

1. Path ("temp2" above) is the place that the "pointer" points to.
2. Only hostname (computer name, or ip) the "pointer" won't work.

---

In my case, the device with a microcontroller (single chip computer) has only limited interfaces, where data are stored differently from a PC. Hence, fs.readdir won't work.

Thanks to hints from @jfriend00, I managed to get the communication protocol, and succeeded in reading the data from the device with Nodejs. Codes are given as an example below (for beginers like me).

---

```
//instruction packet from protocol: 
//header: 0xA5 0x5A
//length: 0x00 0x05 
//instruction code: 0x52 (device response depending on this code)
//parameters: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x05
//ending: 0x0D 0x0A

const net = require ('net');
const hexString = "A55A000552000000050D0A";//0xA5 0x5A 0x00 0x05 0x52 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x05 0x0D 0x0A
const reqHex = Buffer.from(hexString, 'hex'); 
var client = new net.Socket();

client.connect(8080, '192.168.4.1', () => {
    console.log('Connected to device at 8080');
    client.write(reqHex);
});

client.on('data', (data) => { //listen to data response from device
    console.log('Received from device: ' + data);
    client.destroy();
});

client.on('close', () => {
    console.log('Connection to device closed');
});
```

---